# Reconstructing canvas path using co-ordinates

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am making an app implementing the FingerPaint Api, with an aim to draw from one screen to another which I have done. My problem now is that I have added a list view to the bottom of the screen the co-ordinates are being sent to. Due to this and taking into account users with smaller screens, I have decided to send over the size of the screen being drawn on and then calculated a difference in screen size (width and height independently) by dividing the receiving devices screen size by the senders to get a ratio which I then multiply all co-ordinates by.

e.g (receiver-width/sender-width) * co-ordinate = new x co-ordinate

I feel this should work to scale down the co-ordinates correctly.

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to scale down the drawing, bearing in mind the path is drawn in real time.

Comment: I've done this before (not for android) and it worked well (in real time)